# Scroll not working in ios5 xcode 4.2

Tags: uitableview, scroll

I had an older example which had a scrolling tableview. The scroll bars are not appearing any longer when I moved to the new xcode/ios combination. In fact, I tried the other sample code on developer site which had scrolling and none of them are working. I was wondering if there is anything I am missing out on or if there is an already known bug which I should be aware of.